# Operator with C# dynamic?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, clr

I have this function:

```
static void Func1<T>(T x, T y)
{
    dynamic result = ((dynamic)x + y); //line 1
    dynamic result2 = (x + y);         //line 2
}
```

This func can be executed as `Func(1,2);` However, line 1 is *OK*, while line 2 goes *BANG* (at compile time).

The exception thrown from line 2 is:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

So, we need to create an operator overload. Okay, so far so good.

**But what about line 1? Shouldn't it need a dynamic cast also on `y`?**

`((dynamic)x + (dynamic)y);`

I understand that it is being evaluated at runtime, but why does the C# compiler accept the `+` operator  in line 1 (i.e. wrongly assume that T can be `+` to something else)?

Comment: What is the value in `result` after executing the code?  Is it '3' or '12'.  My guess is it's doing string concatenation.

Comment: @Servy: What makes you think that it would do string concatenation when `T` is `int`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example, by making `x` a `dynamic` you've in effect made the `operator+` operation dynamic as well. This gets rid of the type specifier `T` for `x`, thereby getting rid of the complaint that `T` has no valid `operator+`.

At run time *dynamic binding* will occur and evaluate the two operands to ensure that `operator+` can be used:

> If an operand of an arithmetic operator has the compile-time type dynamic, then the expression is dynamically bound (§7.2.2). In this case the compile-time type of the expression is dynamic, and the resolution described below will take place at run-time using the run-time type of those operands that have the compile-time type dynamic.

In your second example, the compiler knows the types for `x + y` and is simply storing the result into a `dynamic` variable. Further usages of `result2` will be dynamically bound. This makes sense as there are no dynamic operations to the *right* of the assignment operator:

> When no dynamic expressions are involved, C# defaults to static binding, which means that the compile-time types of constituent expressions are used in the selection process.

Comment: Plus, I have to wonder why you would make a generic method try to use type specific operators without a constraint.

Comment: Well, for something like numeric types you can't come up with any type constraint which would allow arithmetic operations.

Comment: I would think the preferred way would simply be to make overloads for those specific value types like the framework does. Otherwise, if you want to have specific types perform some kind of operation like that, make them implement a specific interface and then constrain to that interface.

Comment: A contrived example would be trying to implement `Complex<T>`. Neither interfaces, overloads, nor generics would allow you to implement arithmetic operations using syntax alone.

Comment: so it is enough for 1 argument to be dynamic so the whole expression will be ealuated dynamic ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: as far as my understanding of the standard. However, in the case of mutually exclusive sub-expressions like `((dynamic)x + y) * (x + y)`, the compiler knows that it can *statically* bind `(x + y)` and reports the `CS0019` error like in your second example.

Answer (score 3):

`dynamic` basically tells the compiler "don't try to make sure what I'm doing is legal; I'm sure it will be at runtime". Any operation you attempt on a variable of dynamic type will compile. It just won't run successfully if the type assigned to the dynamic variable doesn't actually implement the operation.

As for why both of them don't have to be dynamic, the compiler will basically try to find an operator (static method) on either of the types involved in the operation that matches the signature, starting with the LValue. With the LValue being dynamic, the compiler must assume the operation exists on anything that will be used as X, even though X is of the same placeholder type as Y and Y is not known to have a + operator.